# How to apply clut (Color Lookup Table) using ImageMagick command line

Tags: colors, imagemagick

IamgeMagick dcouments its `-clut` option as "Replace the channel values in the first image using each corresponding channel in the second image as a color lookup table...This operator is especially suited to replacing a grayscale image with a specific color gradient from the CLUT image."

Ok, so I have `IN.png`  (greyscale, 800x259) and `Gradient.png` (1x256, colored). The documentation suggests (but does not say) that the command should be `convert IN.png Gradient.png -clut OUT.png`. However, that just copies `Gradient.png` to `OUT.png`. (Bitwise identical, even). Reversing the first two arguments will copy `IN.png` to `OUT.png`, again unmodified.

The desired result is of course a 800x259 colored image, using the values from `IN.png` and the colors from `Gradient.png`. What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: What is your ImageMagick version and platform?

Comment: 6.6.9 IIRC (not near the machine). Weirdly enough, I finally did get it working. Can't figure out anymore what the difference was. I do remember that my first attempts put `-clut` second, but that resulted in file I/O errors on both the gradient inputy and the output file. That was fairly easily figured out, despite the incorrect error message ("read error" on gradient input)